# Overloading Stream Insertion Operator in a Class Template

Tags: c++, templates

I am a student in a C++ programming course. We were asked to write a class template to perform operations on fractions of different data types.

I managed to overload the operators, but I wanted to overload the stream insertion operator also, to use `cout <<` in the main program. I'm sure that the answer is obvious to anyone but myself. The code is ugly, but I have been trying to hammer square pegs into round holes for two days and haven't brought myself to start from scratch again.

Below is the header file with the class template and member definitions. I originally had the function `friend` declaration in the class definition, and the function definition outside with the rest of the function definitions. This code doesn't generate any compilation errors, but if I try to use `cout <<` in the main program, I get this error:

```
Error   C2275   'fractionType<int>': illegal use of this type as an expression  McElroy_CS285_Week4Assignment   C:\Users\david\source\repos\McElroy_CS285_Week4Assignment\McElroy_CS285_Week4Assignment\fractionType.h  39
```

```cpp
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include<math.h>
#include<iomanip>

using namespace std;

template <class Type>
class fractionType
{
public:
    fractionType()
        : numerator(0), denominator(0)
    {

    }
    fractionType(Type num, Type den)
    {
        numerator = num;
        denominator = den;
    }

    fractionType<Type> operator+(const fractionType<Type>&) const;
    fractionType<Type> operator-(const fractionType<Type>&) const;
    fractionType<Type> operator*(const fractionType<Type>&) const;
    fractionType<Type> operator/(const fractionType<Type>&) const;
    bool operator==(const fractionType<Type>&) const;
    bool operator!=(const fractionType<Type>&) const;
    bool operator>(const fractionType<Type>&) const;
    bool operator<(const fractionType<Type>&) const;
    bool operator>=(const fractionType<Type>&) const;
    bool operator<=(const fractionType<Type>&) const;

    void print(fractionType<Type>);


    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& osObject, fractionType<Type>& fraction)
    {
        osObject << fractionType.numerator << fractionType.denominator;
        return osObject;
    }

private:
    Type numerator;
    Type denominator;
};

template<class Type>
fractionType<Type> fractionType<Type>::operator+(const fractionType<Type>& fraction) const
{
    fractionType<Type> tempFraction;

    tempFraction.numerator = (numerator * fraction.denominator) + (fraction.numerator * denominator);
    tempFraction.denominator = fraction.denominator * denominator;

    return tempFraction;
}

template<class Type>
fractionType<Type> fractionType<Type>::operator-(const fractionType& fraction) const
{
    fractionType tempFraction;

    tempFraction.numerator = (numerator * fraction.denominator) - (fraction.numerator * denominator);
    tempFraction.denominator = fraction.denominator * denominator;

    return tempFraction;
}

template<class Type>
fractionType<Type> fractionType<Type>::operator*(const fractionType& fraction) const
{
    fractionType tempFraction;

    tempFraction.numerator = numerator * fraction.numerator;
    tempFraction.denominator = denominator * fraction.denominator;

    return tempFraction;
}

template<class Type>
fractionType<Type> fractionType<Type>::operator/(const fractionType& fraction) const
{
    fractionType tempFraction;

    tempFraction.numerator = numerator * fraction.denominator;
    tempFraction.denominator = fraction.numerator * denominator;

    return tempFraction;
}

template<class Type>
bool fractionType<Type>::operator==(const fractionType& fraction) const
{
    return (numerator / denominator == fraction.numerator / fraction.denominator);
}

template<class Type>
bool fractionType<Type>::operator!=(const fractionType& fraction) const
{
    return(numerator / denominator != fraction.numerator / fraction.denominator);
}

template<class Type>
bool fractionType<Type>::operator>(const fractionType& fraction) const
{
    return(numerator / denominator > fraction.numerator / fraction.denominator);
}
    
template<class Type>
bool fractionType<Type>::operator<(const fractionType& fraction) const
{
    return(numerator / denominator < fraction.numerator / fraction.denominator);
}

template<class Type>
bool fractionType<Type>::operator>=(const fractionType& fraction) const
{
    return(numerator / denominator >= fraction.numerator / fraction.denominator);
}

template<class Type>
bool fractionType<Type>::operator<=(const fractionType& fraction) const
{
    return(numerator / denominator <= fraction.numerator / fraction.denominator);
}

template<class Type>
void fractionType<Type>::print(fractionType<Type> fraction)
{
    cout << fraction.numerator << "/" << fraction.denominator << endl;
}
```

Comment: You want `fraction.numerator` and `fraction.denominator` instead of `fractionType.numerator` and `fractionType.denominator`.

Comment: Oh man. Seriously? That was it. Thank you!! I have been beating my face off of the keyboard all day over this. It worked fine until I added the template. I couldn't figure out what went wrong to save my life.

Comment: `fractionType` and `fraction` are colored differently, you should have noticed it.

Comment: On a side note, you probably want your `operator<<` to include a ```/``` delimiter between the `numerator` and `denominator` values, like `print()` does. Which BTW, is redundant and should be removed completely (it wasn't coded correctly anyway - there is no good reason for it to take a `fractionType` as a parameter when it is already being called on a `fractionType` object. It should access its values via the implicit `this` pointer instead, eg: `template<class Type>void fractionType<Type>::print() const { cout << numerator << "/" << denominator << endl; }`).

Comment: @BenniShogun -- I suggest you fully code `operator ==` and `operator <`, and not the other operators.  All of the other operators should be written in terms of those two operators -- you shouldn't be coding those other operators "from scratch" like you're doing now.  For example: `operator !=(const fractionType& fraction) const { return !(*this == fraction); }` and `operator > (const fractionType& fraction) const { return fraction < *this; }`

Comment: @BenniShogun -- Just to say why you should do as I suggested -- 1) The other operators will naturally do the "right thing", instead of you having to write code turning things inside out to get the operators to work.  2) Related to 1), you open yourself up for bugs by writing unnecessary code.

Comment: @BenniShogun -- [See this](https://godbolt.org/z/hb3E6EWY3).  All of the relational operators are written in terms of `==` and `<`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @273K wrote, you should use the variable name (`fraction`), not the type name (`fractionType`). Additionally, you take non-const reference in your `operator<<`. Suggest taking const ref:

```
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& osObject, const fractionType<Type>& fraction)
    {
        osObject << fraction.numerator << fraction.denominator;
        return osObject;
    }
```

Comment: Thank You!! It was originally a constant reference, but I changed a bit of everything while trying to get a different result. Now that the problem is fixed, I will go back through and try to knock all the dents. I'm new to Stack Exchange. I really appreciate the fast feedback!! You guys are awesome!!

Comment: @BenniShogun Thanks for the praises :), people here try to do the best. If you're ok with the answer, you can accept it via the checkmark next to the vote arrows.